# Hide tabs within a tabbed control in Access

Tags: ms-access, tabs, navigation

I have two tabs in my tabbed control and want to hide the tabs / tab names at the top of it as I want users to access the each tab using dedicated sidebar buttons (which I have created and which work).

Is it possible to hide the tabs at the top of the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Format > Style = "Tabs". If you set this to "None" the tabs row will not appear.

[image]

Alternatively, have oyu considered using a Navigation form?

[image]

Comment: He, I never noticed this property. :)

Comment: @Andre it's not well named for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `TabFixedHeight` property to something very small, like 0.001 cm.

This works for me in Access 2010 with `UseTheme = True`.

Comment: I have tried this, but when viewed in Form View, one of the fields in the second tab is visible as an overlaying element within the first tab.  Also, the content in the first tab is not appearing at the top of the form as it should - it is appearing lower down, as if the tabs were still visible (even though they are no longer visible).